# Phonegap : cannot open iOS 6 native maps application

Tags: ios, cordova, dictionary

I've got an issue with an app builded on phonegap build (build.phonegap.com) on iOS with Phonegap 2.3.
I'm trying to open the native map application with this link :

`<a id="gmap_image" href="">
</a>`

The js code that sets the href attribute :

`$("#gmap_image").href('http://maps.apple.com/?q='+$xml.find( "adresse" ).text());`

I've seen that for opening native maps application with a link, i have to give an url based on maps.apple.com domain ([Apple Map Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)).

But when I click on the link, all that happens is that the page refreshes (and I don't know why it refreshes too because no code asks to do it).

Has someone an idea ?

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe it's too late, but i had the same issue.

Try this way:

```
$("#gmap_image").href('maps:q='+$xml.find( "adresse" ).text());
```

just change `http://maps.apple.com/?q=` into `maps:q=` 
that works for me

Comment: I saw this worked yay :) thank you anyway ! People should read what you write here, not Apple documentation...

Comment: Useful summary of ios and android map URI schemes: https://gist.github.com/danharper/844382901f7a7b73b90a

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the google Maps app on an iOS device using this header in the URL Scheme. comgooglemaps://  This is according to the developer documentation found here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

for example a web link to open the Google Maps app in iOS6 and get directions from New York to Washington DC would look like this.

```
    <a href="comgooglemaps://?saddr=New+York,+NY&daddr=Washington+DC&directionsmode=driving">Directions from New York, NY to Washington DC</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('#map').bind('tap', function(){
    var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?';
    url += 'q=[place_name]'; //add ur querystrings

    // open the native maps app by calling window location
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I tried your piece of code but it's opening maps.google.com in the same webview than the app. I would like it to open native iOS map application and quit my first app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a no-go on iOS 6, since Google maps is no longer "natively" part of the OS.

Though you can still launch Apple Maps, since this is supported natively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the latest PhoneGap/Cordova versions, it seems that it's not longer possible to open safari or maps from standard "a href=xxx" tags.

In order to open maps, you will need to attach a click event and open the link using:

```
 window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?q=whavever', '_system');
```

within Phonegap, window.open() will open a link with a new in app browser, but, if you specify '_system' as the second param, it will send the URL to the OS (thus, opening the maps app in this situation).